# How to export addons models from blender 3.00 to blender 3.6?

Tags: modeling, export, conversion

I'm using 2 addons in my project: "buildify" and "Post USSR builder". Bot first one works only on blender 3.2+ and second one works only 3.0 and earlier. And when I'm trying to export buildings from "post ussr builder" they are just turning to nothing or exporting without textures. Can someone help with this pls? As I understand, they are using built-in blender instruments. I tried to turn object to mesh and its dissapeared.
P.s. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Have you tried to convert your models to mesh?

Comment: Contact the addon author(s). We can't help with third-party addons here. Also if you're losing textures when exporting, see this : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: @Emir Yes, i tried, it's disappears :(

Comment: @JohnEason As I understand - it uses built-in blender instruments, because it opens as usual project file

Comment: You should add links to the add-ons. I guess it's https://paveloliva.gumroad.com/l/buildify and https://kypcaht.gumroad.com/l/PmCLJ. It looks like the "Post USSR builder" uses Geometry Nodes (Blender 2.9x). It will not work in Blender 3.x because Geometry Nodes changed a lot between Blender versions 2.9x and 3.0. For example, [Fields](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/fields.html) have been introduced. I'm not sure what you want to do. Do you use the add-ons with Blender 3.6? How do you export the created models?

Comment: Both buildify and Post USSR builder that you say you're using are external addons which aren't included with Blender. You haven't said what Blender version you're using or provided any images of Blender's screen (Window > save Screenshot in Blender then edit and insert into your question), and we'll probably need to see a blend file too.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: @Blunder all I want to do is export the resulting objects to newer version of blender somehow. I thought that it's possible to somehow turn the models from the generated object into something like a regular mesh with texture preservation. To transfer them from the old version to the new one and use as uneditable mesh .

Comment: @JohnEason I said that I'm using blender 3.0 and 3.6 right it the name of the question)
Here is file with post ussr builder (opens only in blender 3.0), I want to export buildings from it to newest version without loosing textures

Comment: If you just want to move objects from one blend file to another I would use "File > Append..." rather than import/export. Because import/export always converts the mesh (applies all modifiers, can mess up the textures, triangulates the mesh, etc). The objects are no longer in Blender's native data format. Better move the objects that you want to transfer to a new collection, and save the blend file. Then open the new blend file and use the main menu entry "File > Append ... ".  Navigate to *Collections* and select the collection that you want to transfer. It will add everything that is in it.

Comment: @JohnEason https://blend-exchange.com/b/WZZ9bzOQ

Comment: @Blunder I tried to use Append, but it exports only assets without final building... I shared link, could you help and try to export buildings from it?

Comment: @Blunder Oh, I finally understanded how to export them with "Append", I converted buildings into meshes with "make instances real" and exported to newer version of blender! Thank u very much!

Answer (score 0):

I converted buildings into meshes with "make instances real" and exported to newer version of blender with "Append"